# how to import interface from Firebase Messaging from Admin SDK?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

sorry I am newbie in Typescript and Node.

when sending FCM message in Typescript using Admin SDK, we can use this method

```
sendToDevice(registrationToken: string | string[], payload: MessagingPayload, options?: MessagingOptions): Promise<MessagingDevicesResponse>;
```

that code taken from `index.d.ts` from firebase admin

when I want to use that method, I want to restrict the variable I create like this

```
const myPayload : MessagingPayload = {
    data: notification.toObject(),
    notification: {
        title: notification.title,
        body: notification.body,
        image: notification.imagePath,
    },
};

await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, myPayload, options);
```

but I need to import `MessagingPayload` first.

[image]

but now I am confused how to get / import that `MessagingPayload` interface

I try to import using this code below but it is error:

```
import { MessagingPayload } from "firebase-admin";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each product's types are namespaced under the main export.  You can write it like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
const myPayload : admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = { ... }
```

Or if you want to abbreviate it yourself, or change it completely:

```
type MessagingPayload = admin.messaging.MessagingPayload
const myPayload : MessagingPayload = { ... }
```